# Chromecast subtitles on default receiver applications

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to include subtitles on a Chromecast application I'm building.

1. I am using the default receiver application.
2. I am writing a chrome sender application using v1 of the chrome sender api.

According to the [Chromecast Sender Api documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.Track), I should be passing in an array of track objects into the chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo object. My issue is, whenever I call `chrome.cast.media.Track(trackId, trackType)`, it returns undefined. When I look through the public methods in `chrome.cast.media`, through console, I don't see anything related to Track. Link to documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.Track).

Below is my loadMedia method where I try to include an array of track objects along with my `LoadRequest` as specified by the cast api. The commented out code is how I've seen closed-captioning handled in one of the cast Github repositories, but unfortunately I believe you have to handle that customData in your own custom receiver application.

Are subtitles through the chrome sender SDK possible yet, or does one have to build their own receiver application and specifically handle text tracking through passed in customData? Am I potentially using the wrong sender api?

```
function loadMedia() {
  mediaUrl = decodeURIComponent(_player.sources.mp4);
  var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(mediaUrl);
  mediaInfo.contentType = 'video/mp4';

  var track1 = new chrome.cast.media.Track(1, chrome.cast.media.TrackType.TEXT);
  track1.trackContentId = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35106650/test.vtt";

  mediaInfo.tracks = [track1];
  var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);

  // var json = {
  //   cc: {
  //     tracks: [{
  //       src: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35106650/test.vtt"
  //     }],
  //     active: 0
  //   }
  // };

  // request.customData = json;
  session.loadMedia(request, onMediaDiscovered.bind(this, 'loadMedia'), onMediaError);
}
```

Comment: @JakeGould not really sure what you mean. Apologies if my question came across to you as an RFP to do work...I've been trying to build subtitle functionality using my sender application and the default receiver app. When I try to create the Track object specified in Google's documentation, it seems like it's not part of the API. Just knowing that someone else has had this issue trying to use the current Cast api would in itself be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, neither the Default nor the Styled Receivers support Closed Caption; you need to create your own. We have a sample [in our GitHub repo](http://github.com/googlecast/CastClosedCaptioning-chrome) that can be used for doing exactly that.

Update: Styled and Default receivers now support Tracks, see our [documentations](https://developers.google.com/cast/).

Comment: People who get to use Cast SDK wold know about our sample repo on GitHub, here it is for those who don't: https://github.com/googlecast/CastClosedCaptioning-chrome

Comment: Thanks @AliNaddaf. I did find the SDK a bit ambiguous on implementation of subtitles. Working on building the custom receiver! Thanks!

Comment: @AliNaddaf any plans to support subtitles for the default receiver? It should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: We will support that in future.

Comment: The section labled "Using the Tracks API" states:

Note: Currently, the Styled and Default Media Receivers allow you to use only the text tracks with the API. To work with the audio and video tracks, you must develop a Custom Receiver.

So it seems as if the VTT text tracks should work as explained but I can not get it to actually load some tracks. The default receiver fails to load when Track objects are in the tracks array of the MediaInfo.

Does the default receiver actually support the VTT text tracks or am I reading this page wrong: 
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender

Comment: It does support VTT text.