# Cast Receiver App does not show subtitles

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

According to the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes) (of July 8), the docs for the [Sender](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender) and the updated answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549445/chromecast-subtitles-on-default-receiver-applications), the Styled Media Receiver of Google Cast does now support Closed Captioning or Subtitle tracks.

However, when I tell the Default or the Styled Media Receiver to show a text track, nothing happens. It does not even load the `.vtt` from the server, as I can see in the logs.

I can tell the receiver app got the text tracks just fine, but even using the [Android example app](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android), the subtitles never show up. According to all the logs, they are being sent and the receiver app is told to show them - but they never appear, they are never even loaded.

The `MediaTrack` is being created as follows:

```
new MediaTrack.Builder(2, MediaTrack.TYPE_TEXT)
             .setName("Deutsch")
             .setSubtype(MediaTrack.SUBTYPE_CAPTIONS)
             .setContentId("https://example.com/video/caption_de.vtt")
             .setContentType("text/vtt")
             .setLanguage("de").build();
```

I have checked thrice that the file exists and is being loaded with the type `text/vtt`. But that does not matter, as the file is never even requested by the player. I have tried both `MediaTrack.SUBTYPE_CAPTIONS` and `MediaTrack.SUBTYPE_SUBTITLES`.

So I need to know, is this claimed support of CC in the Styled Media Receiver simply a lie? Or is there some undocumented trick required to make it possible?

If there is still a custom receiver required, I would like to know how to convert the [example player](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample) to support subtitles, as it doesn't seem to support them either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest you change your wording in future posts (re: "..is simply a lie.."); that is not appropriate at all. Secondly, it works and you can test that with the CastVideos-android app (or ios variation of it for that matter); the first three videos have CC. Lastly, we have documentation on that subject on our documentation site (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender, under "Using the Tracks API").

Comment: I apologise for my wording but after three hours of following every tutorial to a T, I'm a bit frustrated. In fact, I *am* using the CastVideos-android app, all I did was replacing the Cast Application ID and the URLs in the json file, to an `.m3u8` stream and my own `.vtt` files. But they are never loaded.

Comment: Does it work for the the CastVideos-android without you making any changes?

Comment: I re-cloned the CastVideos-android app and put in my own cast application ID. The Subtitles are showing fine. I then replaced the `.json` with the videos and the tracks with this one: https://neighr.com/hls/movies.json . The subtitles stop working. The app does not even request the files from the server. Please, please, please tell me what I did wrong, I think I'm getting insane here.

Comment: Your next step is to look at the console logs to see what is going on (I suggest a Styled receiver). Are you providing CORS for your vtt stream? I am assuming you are not using a segmented closed caption?

Comment: The .vtt is just a plain file and the CORS is set properly for all files. But the .vtt is not even requested, so CORS is not the issue. Will try to get my Cast to give me some console output tomorrow.

Comment: All right I used the developer tools on the Chromecast, and got no errors at all. Then, out of desperation, I replaced `.m3u8` file with an `.mp4` of Sintel. Amazingly, the Subtitles are loaded and show up properly. So my final conclusion is that `.vtt` captions do not work on HLS streaming. Is this a bug? Should I file a bug somewhere?

Comment: Since you are using HLS and you have a vtt file, you need to write your own custom receiver to handle this; currently the Styled/Default receivers do not handle such case. It is likely that such support will be added in future but no time frame is set on that.

Comment: @AliNaddaf, I experience the same issue, and it's really annoying (I spent hours trying to find what's wrong with my code), because the documentation doesn't say a word about this. Please, at least update the docs, to warn the developers.